# Frequent file writing causes memory leak in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks

I encontered this problem on my CentOS 7 system.

Try this script:

```
import time

while True:
    with open ('~/test.txt','a') as file:
        file.write('abcdefg\n')
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Save it as "test.py".

Run:
`systemd-run --unit=test python3.6 ~/test.py`

Monitor the memory usage by using `systemd-cgtop`. You will see that the memory usage of "test" is continually increasing.

Update:
I tried this on Windows and it didn't cause memory leak. So this may be a system-specific problem. Is there a way to get around this on Linux?

Comment: It could definitely be a bug, but given the fact that's such a common (and widely used) feature, I'd rather say it's not. I think it's a matter of *Python*'s **garbage collection** and/or buffering. Maybe [\[Python\]: Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) contains some useful info.

Comment: @CristiFati I tried this script on windows 8.1 and it didn't cause memory leak. So this might be a system-specific problem.

Comment: I don't know how relevant the _Win_ behavior is. some code differs across platforms. I ran the script without _systemd_ on a _Ubtu_ til the file was 2MB+, but I didn't see any memory increase in _top_.

Comment: @CristiFati It turned out that `systemd-cgtop` captured physical memory and cached memory. That was why it appeared to be memory leaking.

Comment: Nice to hear that the root cause was pinpointed! You should probably write an answer to your own question and mark it as such.